# "cut -f values" validation by regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to create in perl my own version of Unix's cut command. I would like to validate values given to -f option.

Here is an example, how my perl script should be executed properly:

```
perl mycut -f -47,49,53,56-60,71-
```

I would like to validate those numbers, typed by user. I tried something like that:

```
(([1-9]+[0-9]*[-][1-9]+[0-9]*)|([1-9]+[0-9]*[-]+)|([-]?[1-9]+[0-9]*))+,?
```

but it returns true if user types for example: -2-5 which is incorrect.

correct examples:

```
-7,10,21,23-33,39-80,99,116-120
21-25,32,33,41
1,2,4,5-
7
```

not "so nice" like above, but I can handle them:

```
32,17,-4,15,22-
-7,14-,15,2,6,18-
11,81,65-69,18,2,81
```

incorrect:

```
0
1,2,3,4,-5-6
-1-2,0,2,17-18
-25,28,-29-30,32
0,1,2,3,4,5
0-1,2-3
-2-7,9,11-
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Could you give a list of examples taht should match, and another one that shouldnt... or explain better what the correct structure should be...

Comment: Done. With -f option, you specify a list of fields assumed to be separated. For example, if you specify -f 1,7, the cut command writes out only the first and seventh fields. (I've copied and transformed definition from IBM)

Comment: I found [`this`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds1%2Fcut.htm) man page to help understand the structure if someone else trying to help...

Comment: Check [`this pattern`](http://regex101.com/r/iQ4kE5)... It simply doesnt accept values containing `0` nor those having `-xx-xx` structure... Is there any other case I missed ?

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm sorry, I forgot to say that "-" sign can be used only once per range, for example `27-30-` is also incorrect. The only three correct values are: `-XXXX,XXXX-XXXX,XXXX-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to do way too much with a regular expression. Even if you get it to work, will the people who have to support it ever understand it?

You're better off if you use `split` to split out each field specification, and then check each one separately:

```
my @fields = split /,/, $field_parameter; # Split -f param on commas
for my $field ( @fields ) {
   if ( not $field =~ /^\d+-\d+$/    # 1-3
        and not $field =~ /^\d+$/    # 3
        and not $field =~ /^-\d+$/   # -3
        and not $field =~ /^\d+-$/   # 3-
      ) {
         die qq(Invalid field specification "$field".);
   }
}
```

I could have specified a single `if` and a single regular expression, but again the poor coworker who takes over my code after I get a better job has to support this mess. Here I specify each possible way the parameter could be arrange. If there's a bug, or the field specs get changed, it's easy to figure out the code.

Comment: It's acutally much better idea. Thank you!